# catch errors using pydantic @validator decorator for fastapi input query

Tags: python, validation, fastapi, pydantic

I have 2 issues that I cannot tackle so far using docs/goole/stack info :-)

**1) How shall I catch ValidationErrors thrown by pydantic model validator decorator when using model as query input for fastapi get query?**

context:

I have a pydantic model:

```
class PointRankReqParams(BaseModel):
    rat: Optional[Literal['2G', '3G', '4G', '5G']] = '3G'
    h3resolution: Optional[int] = 5
    input_srid: Optional[int] = 4326
    bufferdistance: Optional[int] = 5000
    x: float 
    y: float 

    @validator('h3resolution')
    def h3resolution_bins(cls, v):
        if v not in [4,5,6,7,8]:
            raise ValueError('Hexabin size not permitted')
        return v
```

and FastAPI func that serves GET requests:

```
@router.get("/point/overall", summary="GET Ranking for given location point")
async def get_ranking_for_location_point(inputparams: PointRankReqParams = Depends(),token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):    
    logger.debug("Here I am")
    return {}
```

Now when I curl with parameter *h3resolution* beyond defined range e.g
`http://localhost:9000/rank/point/overall?rat=2G&h3resolution=9&input_srid=4326&bufferdistance=5000&x=21&y=21`
I get errors in console that actually makes sense

```
py-    |   File "pydantic/main.py", line 406, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
py-    | pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for PointRankReqParams
py-    | h3resolution
py-    |   Hexabin size not permitted (type=value_error)
```

But FastAPI returns HTTP 500 Internal Server Error to end-client.
**How shall I catch those exceptions that comes from validator?**

---

**2. How to use Optional[Literal[...]] construction properly?**

I've tried to redefine above example to use in model:

```
class PointRankReqParams(BaseModel):
...
h3resolution: Optional[Literal[4,5,6,7,8]] = 5
```

But when I curl GET query
e.g `http://localhost:9000/rank/point/overall?rat=2G&h3resolution=7&input_srid=4326&bufferdistance=5000&x=21&y=21`
I receive 422 Unprocessable entry as *h3resolution* is being interpreted as string not integer:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "query",
        "h3resolution"
      ],
      "msg": "unexpected value; permitted: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8",
      "type": "value_error.const",
      "ctx": {
        "given": "7",
        "permitted": [
          4,
          5,
          6,
          7,
          8
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is really good question! That's been discussed for several years, you can check this [github issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/318). And unfortunately, there's no consensus on how to handle it, [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#classes-as-dependencies_1) just shows a simple use case using plain Python classes. It works with `BaseModel` and `dataclass` until you want to have custom validators or something, FastAPI's author [says](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/318#issuecomment-584087181):

> Having a single Pydantic model for query parameters could be
> interpreted as:
>
> `http://somedomain.com/?args={"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}`
>
> or
>
> `http://somedomain.com/?k1=v1&k2=v2`
>
> or many other alternatives...
>
> And we are not even discussing sub-models, that are valid in Pydantic
> models (and request bodies) but the behavior would be undefined for
> non-body parameters (query, path, etc).
>
> There's no obvious way to go about how it would be interpreted that
> works for all the cases (including other people's use cases, future
> use cases, etc).
>
> So it doesn't really make sense to have it in FastAPI for a custom use
> case as it's very subjective and dependent on the conventions of the
> team.

[jimcarreer](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/318#issuecomment-581027959) suggested using something like:

```
class PagingQuery(BaseModel):
    page: conint(ge=1)
    page_size: conint(ge=1, le=250) = 50

    @classmethod
    async def depends(cls, page: int = 1, page_size: int = 50):
        try:
            return cls(page=page, page_size=page_size)
        except ValidationError as e:
            errors = e.errors()
            for error in errors:
                error['loc'] = ['query'] + list(error['loc'])
            raise HTTPException(422, detail=errors)


@app.get("/example", tags=["basic"])
def example(paging: PagingQuery = Depends(PagingQuery.depends)):
    return {"page": paging.page, "page_size": paging.page_size}
```

But that looks hacky and I would rather stay away from it.

Answering your second question, the query string is just a string (like `'age=20&name=John'`) and key, value pairs are just strings; you have specified `Literal` type, so there won't be type casting and you'll get an exception.